# Find confidence interval of fitting parameter by varying chi squared

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, fitting

I have an assignment where 1750 data points are compared with a fitting function that uses 3 parameters. It is given that, at the best fit, the value of the reduced chi-squared statistic is about $\chi^2_\nu\approx7$, so that $\chi^2=1747\chi^2_\nu\approx12,229$. The instruction is to vary each of the fit parameters individually in both directions so that the chi-squared statistic increases by $\Delta\chi^2=11.5$, and use the corresponding parameter values as the bounds of their 99% confidence intervals.

I have been trying (without success) to motivate the value $\Delta\chi^2=11.5$. Please could someone shed a light on how you arrive at this value from $p=0.99$?

Comment: Do you know what the degrees of freedom for the $\chi^2_{\nu}$ are?

Comment: The correct value for $p=0.99$ is $11.34487$, as found in any table of the $\chi^2(3)$ distribution.  @jbowman it's easy to overlook the passing reference to the df in the opening sentence: the test is based on the three parameters being varied for the fit.

Comment: @whuber - I saw that, but wasn't sure that the OP realized that's what $\nu$ equalled, which might have been the source of his confusion.

Comment: @jbowman and whuber thanks for your comments. I hadn’t clocked that $\nu=3$. I’m still not entirely sure why (I thought it was 1750 – 3 = 1747?), but perhaps I am fundamentally misunderstanding how $\chi^2$ applies to data vs how it applies to a model